With Web Streams, how can I distinguish if a readable stream is compressed (gzip) or not?
I have a client-side JS aapplication where I want to use Web Streams to process some input file from the user. The file could either be a text file (in which case I just pipe it through a TextDecoderStream and then do whatever I want with it) or a gzipped text file (in which case I need to pipe it through a DecompressionStream before it gets to the TextDecoderStream).
What's the best way to handle this?
I could make the user manually click a checkbox for compressed or not, but that's poor UI.
I could look at the filename of the uploaded file, but that may not always be accurate.
I guess ideally I'd write some DecompressionStreamIfNecessary transform stream that I could just pipe through and it would decompress the stream if necessary or do nothing otherwise. idk if that's possible though.
What's the best way to do this?

Simply try to decompress, and if that fails, process it as text. The decompressor will likely give up in the first byte or two, since a text file won't have a gzip header.

I get that in theory. Or look directly at the first 2 bytes to see if it's gzip. But I'm just struggling with how to exactly implement it in the context of web streams. Like how to say "check the first 2 bytes, if they match the gzip header then pipe the stream through this other transform, but if not then just pass through unchanged".

Trying to decompress is better, since it will very quickly turn a false positive on the first two bytes into a true negative.

Good point for the general case, but in my case it's JSON data where the first character is { so that's not a concern.

If you're going to check just a few bytes, then check three: 1f 8b 08.

I came up with this which seems to work, but the API is kind of ugly, it would be nicer if this was just a TransformStream I could pipe through. I would accept an answer from someone who is able to do that!
// Check first 2 bytes of stream for gzip header
const isStreamGzipped = async (stream: ReadableStream) => {
    const reader = stream.getReader();
    const { value } = await reader.read();
    reader.cancel();

    if (value !== undefined && value.length >= 2) {
        return value[0] === 0x1f && value[1] === 0x8b;
    }

    return false;
}

const decompressStreamIfNecessary = async (inputStream: ReadableStream) => {
    const [checkGzipStream, outputStream] = inputStream.tee();

    if (await isStreamGzipped(checkGzipStream)) {
        return outputStream.pipeThrough(
            new DecompressionStream("gzip")
        );
    }

    return outputStream;
};

(await decompressStreamIfNecessary(stream))
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
    .pipeTo(whatever);


